# Create a custom PictureScrollField

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-jde

I want to create a custom `PictureScrollField` to manage the distance between the images. When using it, and specifying different `HighlightStyles`, I can obtain what I want but I want to change the space between the images. I didn't find any function to minimize the space between them or set it to 0 or -10 for example. How can I do this. I thought creating a custom `PictureScrollField` will resolve this but I don't know what I will have to put in the paint(Graphics) function. Using Super.paint will not make this.

So how can I realize this using `PictureScrollField`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at `PictureScrollField.setImageDistance(int gap);` ? It isn't available until OS 6.0 so if you are using OS 5.0 you may be out of luck.

Comment: I am using os 5.0 so I cant use this function. If you see the new release of BB App World you will see what I mean by eliminating the distance between the pictures. They run it on OS 5.0 but how?

Comment: Applications from RIM can use features that have not been released to the public API.